# Specific validation

Tags: validation, associations, unique

I have models User and Product in my project. User have some products. I want user products to have unique title only for this user.

For example user1 has a product titled "product". In this case user2 also can have a product titled "product". First "product" differs from second "product". In table both products have the same name. But the user may not have both of these products at the same time.

That is my Product.rb:

```
validates :title, :description, presence: true

validate :uniq_of_product_title

def uniq_of_product_title
  if Product.where(user_id: user_id).find_by_title(title)
    errors.add(:title, "Product already exists")
  end
end
```

So it works. Problem appears then I edit description and try to update product. Validator finds created product in table and gives a error.

The question is how can I make validates best way?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use regular Rails' `validates` method for this case, try something like:

```
validates :title, uniqueness: true
```

Comment: In this case I can not have product titled "product1" for both users